# Axis Lables Rotation

Tags: highcharts

Hi I am using HighStock 1.2.4

I do have multiple series and separate yAxis for each series. I am calculating `height` and `topPadding` and creating stacked series.

Now, I am facing two problems.

1. I have used `rotation` with yAxis to rotate labels but its not rendering correctly.
   Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mhardik/uZaWz/9/
2. I have also used `rotation` for X Axis labels, but the last series position is getting messed with X Axis Labels.

http://jsfiddle.net/mhardik/uZaWz/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I'm not sure why it's not rendering correctly, if you want to move a little to the left use `x:` property for title.

2) First, I think you need to set proper `align` for xAxis.labels (right). Then make higher chart to make sure you have enough space for a chart.

And jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/uZaWz/12/